# Where can rustc optimization flag details be found?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization, rust-cargo

Sorry if this is documented somewhere, GCC has a [page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) documenting what optimizations have been done in each **optimization level**, also gracefully with simple explanation on each. GCC supports levels including `0`-`3`, `s`, and `z`, etc. In that page, it says when using `-O1`, you turn on flags from `-fauto-inc-dec` to `-funit-at-a-time`, and when using `-O2`, you turn on more like `-falign-functions` and I can read some explanation on them each below.

I know rustc has similar (*at least in their names*) optimization levels, and can be specified using `-Copt-level=#` way, I also know [rustc's doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html?highlight=opt-level#opt-level) provides general explanation on each level, but I couldn't find out what specific optimizations (or, flags) have been done (or, set) in each of them.

**Does rustc has something like doc of optimization flags that I can refer to?** Or I could find them in `LLVM`'s or `Clang`'s doc?

*I would like to dive into it because I wrote some codes (you bet, unsafe) that behaved differently in debug and release profile, so I want to know what optimization(s) might have caused this.*

Comment: There is only [a rough overview in the rustc book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html?highlight=opt-level#opt-level) I don't know what you mean by "same grammar" other than that the levels (0, 1, 2, 3, ..) are loosely based on the ones that `gcc -O` has.

Comment: @cafce25 yes, I mean that both of them are called in the way you wrote (0, 1, 2, 3).To provide some more detail, I wrote a program containing some codes (unsafe though) that behaved differently in debug and release profile, I want to know which optimization might have caused this, so I want to know what optimizations in my `opt-level` had been done.